# How to delete specific file from current directory and its child directory?

Tags: unix, delete-file

I am using command : `rm -r *.c` to delete a file from parent and it's child directory as well. I get this error:

> *.c: No such a file or direcoty.

Comment: Instead of `rm -r`, do `ls -l *.c` and you will see what you are trying to remove.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
find . -name \*.c -type f -delete
```

Answer (score 1):

use the `$find ./ -name *.c | xargs rm`

Answer (score 1):

If your current directory, the one where you execute your command, happens not to have any files `.c` files, your `rm` command will fail.

Use find to gather all the filenames you want to remove and then delete them:

```
find . -name '*.c' -type f | xargs rm
```

Remember to quote the search pattern, here `'*.c'`, otherwise the shell will expand the pattern before running find.